# Add Custom CSS to Woocommerce Product Page in a specified category

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have spent hours researching how to do this but everything I found explains it in a way that goes over my head. I'm not great with coding but I know how to Inspect element and work from there but that doesn't help me in this case.

I want to use a different page layout/template on products in a specified category. I am using [WooCommerce](https://woocommerce.com/) and I was able to use inspect element to recreate a product page the way I desired. Then I have copied the text into the custom css and it works great. However, this ends up being a Global change.

A majority of my product pages would benefit from having the default template rather than the custom one I made. I want to know how to add the code inside of the brackets so that the custom css (custom template) that I've added only gets applied to products in it's designated category.

I hope all that makes sense. Here are pictures to give you a visual example.

[image]

I already know what custom css I want to add to the modified product page template. I hope that designating this custom css to the specific categories is as simple as adding brackets similar to this (sorry, I'm sure it's way wrong but I see custom css that looks similar to this)

.product.category-2 {
   custom css changes here
}

Thanks for taking the time to read this and I appreciate any and all help.

Comment: The body should have a class `term-XX`, where `XX` is the ID of the category. If you add `.term-XX` to the beginning of your CSS rules they'll only apply to that category.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution... Added the following to `functions.php` in my child theme:

```
add_filter( 'body_class','my_body_classes2' );
function my_body_classes2( $classes ) {

if ( is_product() ) {

    global $post;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );

    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $product_cat_id = $term->term_id;
        $classes[] = 'product-in-cat-' . $product_cat_id;    
    }
}
return $classes;
}
```

Now whenever you're viewing a single product page, an additional CSS class for each category the product is in will be added to the `<body>` tag.

Then if you want to change the styling for any single product pages in category 2 or 4, you can use the following CSS:

```
.product-in-cat-2 , .product-in-cat-4 {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Thank you and everyone else for the help! I am going to give this a shot when I get back to the office and let you know how it goes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your funtions.php
https://gist.github.com/thegdshop/3197540

That should add the appropriate category class when on the single prlduct page.

Comment: WordPress already adds a unique class to the body for categories, `term-{id}`

Comment: Really appreciate your feedback. I've seen this talked about in other threads during my search for an answer but this is over my head a bit. I know how to add stuff to the function.php file and more so know how to add custom CSS but i'm not sure what to change and where to put it.

For example, the product category ID is 206. Where would I add that in the functions.php file? After I have placed the product category ID in the correct place, where would I then add the custom css code so that this works?
Is there a way to do this with Custom CSS? Thanks again

Comment: .woocommerce #content div.product div.images, .woocommerce div.product div.images, .woocommerce-page #content div.product div.images, .woocommerce-page div.product div.images {
  width: 100%; }

Comment: Above is an example of code I want to add for the specified product page category.

Comment: @JacobPeattie OP is specifically asking to add a selector to the single product page, not the categories page. Your comment missed the mark entirely, I'm afraid.

Comment: @BlakeShiman the code in the url will add a category "name" class to your body tag. Simply paste in the code at the very end of your functions.php file. Then you'll be able to do something like you've requested: body.category_name .product {your-css} - simply add the code and use the inspector to see the updated body tag.

Answer (score 0):

1) Install plug-in "add costum CSS"

2) This will not display a box to add css by default. You need to go into the plug in (lower part of the admin bar) and there will be a question about "enable costum CSS for following pages" - then check the "products" and you will now have a box to add CSS in individual producs when you go in them through woocommerce.

I don't know if you can do that kind of thing through this method, I needed this for removing render blocking CSS on a product page.

Answer (score 0):

**Add a body class related to the product category in WooCommerce**
Add this to your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'wc_cat_names' );
function wc_cat_names( $classes ) {
    if(is_product()){
    global $post;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            $classes[] = $term->slug;
        }
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have added this code in functions.php file by going

```
dashboard ...>>> appearance >>> editor >>>> functions.php
```

bottom of the code pasted

```
add_filter( 'body_class','my_body_classes2' );
function my_body_classes2( $classes ) {

if ( is_product() ) {

    global $post;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );

    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $product_cat_id = $term->term_id;
        $classes[] = 'product-in-cat-' . $product_cat_id;    
    }
}
return $classes;
}
```

then i goes to 
dashboard ...>>> product >>>> categories >>> 
hover the mouse on edit button and id i got

that same id i placed on single product page

```
.product-in-cat-(ID) {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

it's worked